# How to get DTE object from command-line C++ VSPackage

Tags: c++, visual-studio, envdte, vspackage

I have a C++ VSPackage that is command-line only. Setting the following Autoload registry key in my pkgdef file, does *not* force the VSPackage to get loaded when running devenv from the command line.

```
[$RootKey$\AutoLoadPackages\{ADFC4E64-0397-11D1-9F4E-00A0C911004F}]
"{75726504-cacb-4781-b384-63815a289e0a}"=dword:00000000
@="UICONTEXT_NoSolution"
```

However, if I add a command-line parameter, I can get the VSPackage to load as required:

```
[$RootKey$\AppCommandLine]
"vsp"="{75726504-cacb-4781-b384-63815a289e0a}"

[$RootKey$\AppCommandLine\vsp]
"Arguments"="0"
"DemandLoad"=dword:00000001
"Package"="{75726504-cacb-4781-b384-63815a289e0a}"
"HelpString"="#102"
```

The problem is that when I try to get the DTE object in the OnAfterOpenSolution event, it fails. The same code works when I run devenv in GUI mode.

Is there a better way to get my command-line vspackage to load on startup, or is there a way to get the DTE object using method I'm using above?

Here is the code I use to get DTE:

```
CComPtr<EnvDTE::_DTE> SinkSolutionEvents::GetDTE(CString program)
{
    CString rotEntry;
    rotEntry.Format(L"!VisualStudio.DTE.14.0:%d", program, GetCurrentProcessId());

    IRunningObjectTable *rot = NULL;
    GetRunningObjectTable(0, &rot);
    IEnumMoniker *enumMoniker;
    rot->EnumRunning(&enumMoniker);
    enumMoniker->Reset();
    ULONG fetched = 0;
    IMoniker *moniker = NULL;
    while (enumMoniker->Next(1, &moniker, &fetched) == 0)
    {
        IBindCtx *bindCtx = NULL;
        CreateBindCtx(0, &bindCtx);
        LPOLESTR pwszName;
        HRESULT hr = moniker->GetDisplayName(bindCtx, NULL, &pwszName);
        CString displayName;
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
            displayName = pwszName;
            CoTaskMemFree(pwszName);
            if (displayName == rotEntry)
            {
                CComPtr<IUnknown> punk;
                rot->GetObject(moniker, &punk);
                CComPtr<EnvDTE::_DTE> dte;
                dte = punk;
                return dte;
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: you fail to release bindCtx, moniker and rot. convert those to CComPtr<> to avoid those leaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. You can override IVsPackageImpl::SetSite() and use QueryService on the specified IServiceProvider to get access to EnvDTE.

```
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE MyVSPackage::SetSite( __RPC__in_opt IServiceProvider *pSP)
{
    CComPtr<EnvDTE::_DTE> m_pDTE = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = pSP->QueryService(SID_SDTE, IID__DTE, (void **)&m_pDTE);
    return IVsPackageImpl::SetSite(pSP);
}
```